# Converting a String to a Number in JS

Tags: javascript

Can someone please advise why the 'inputValue' variable in the below function is not being converted into a Number. I was expecting the second `console.log` to report that the variable is now a Number (since I applied `parseInt` to it).
But apparently its still a String.

```
function checkIfNum(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    console.log(inputValue);

    // Convert to a number
    parseInt(inputValue);

    console.log(typeof(inputValue));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't done anything with the *result* of the `parseInt` so as it stands, you are doing `typeof` on the original value of `inputValue` which is a string. Assign the result of `parseInt` to `inputValue` and your code will work fine:

```
function checkIfNum(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    console.log(inputValue);

    // Assign the result of parseInt
    inputValue = parseInt(inputValue, 10);

    console.log(typeof(inputValue));
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0ekf7mn/) (Stack Snippets appears to be down).

It's also worth nothing that I added a radix to your `parseInt` call to ensure it's parsed as decimal on some older browsers.

Comment: Thanks RGraham - one day I'll get a programmer's brain.

Comment: @swisstony Hey, we all make mistakes! It's easier for other people to see problems in code than it is to see your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not assigning the result of `parseInt` to anything, and specifically not to `inputValue`. To correct:

```
inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must store the returned value from `parseInt(inputValue)` as a new variable or overwrite the existing one

```
function checkIfNum(){
var inputValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
console.log(inputValue);

// Convert to a number
var newInputValue = parseInt(inputValue);

console.log(typeof(newInputValue));
}
```